# How to replace a single string with an array?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string `..... one ....` and I have an array that contains images link

```
$my_string = '..... one ....';

$images = [
  "0" => "image_url_1",
  "1" => "image_url_2",
]
```

I need to replace the word `one` with these two images

my code:

```
$pdf_form = ".... <span>one</span> ....";

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $pdf_form = Str::replace('one', '<img src="' . $image . '" />', $pdf_form);
}

dd($pdf_form);
```

The output is, I got just the first image only!

How can I print both images?

Comment: What PHP version you are using?

Comment: @TeerapadPipadboonyarat 8.1

Comment: But you say it prints only one image right? But you assign to $pdf_form it might overwrite it. And I think you should use $image instead of $value

Comment: And what variable do you want to print, and what does it look like in code.

Comment: _"The output is, I got just the first image only!"_ - well _of course_ it is - you replaced `one` with the first image in the first loop iteration, so what `one` do you think was _left_ in the string to be replaced in the second ...?

Comment: @TeerapadPipadboonyarat is HTML code stored in DB, that HTML contains a specific word(one) I need to replace it with these two images! and get the final HTML form!

Comment: @CBroe Yeah u right! I just notice that! So how can I replace one with both?

Comment: By creating a variable that contains the HTML code for both images first, and then replacing `one` with that value _one_ single time ... This is basically what the answer given by JustCode are already suggests, so why are you only commenting "I updated my question" below? I don't see your edit containing anything that would change anything about the basic way to do it, in any relevant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$replace_string=""; 
foreach ($images as $image) {
$replace_string.='<img src="' . $image . '" />';
}
 $pdf_form = Str::replace('one', $replace_string, $my_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see only twos bugs. 1) You use declare $image but never used. Change this: `foreach ($images as $image) {`to `foreach ($images as $value) {`

2. In a loop you will always override the value if you asign the value o variable by using  `=`. Change this to `.=`

#### Update

`$pdf_form .= \St`this line is in your code wrong. You assign with `=` but you have to concat the strings with `.=`

```php
        $pdf_form = ".... <span>one</span> ....";
        $images = ['pic1.png', 'pic2.png'];
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $pdf_form .= \Str::replace('one', '<img src="' . $image . '" />', $pdf_form);
        }

        dd($pdf_form);
```

**output**
`^ ".... <span>one</span> ........ <span><img src="pic1.png" /></span> ........ <span><img src="pic2.png" /></span> ........ <span><img src="pic1.png" /></span> .... ◀"`

Comment: Pls refresh the question I updated it!

Comment: @regosa Thanks for comment. I updated my asnwer. take a look! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display both images each with their own `<img>` tag.

```php
$my_string = '<img src="one" />';

$images = [
  "0" => "image_url_1",
  "1" => "image_url_2",
]

$pdf_form = '';

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $pdf_form = $pdf_form . strtr($my_string, ['one' => $image]);
}
```